# Mobile Push Duplicate Contact Key

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

I am facing issues while doing the Mobile Push implementation. I was just wondering how does the merging happens, as in the below scenario I am getting a duplicate contact key.

1. Install the App on IOS
2. It created a new Contact Key (123456) in Mobile Push
3. Login in the app and the following gets updates for ContactKey 123456

a.       FirstName

b.       LastName

c.       EmailAddress

4. Now uninstall the app
5. Reinstall the app in IOS
6. It created a brand new ContactKey 123457
7. Logged in the app and the following gets created for ContactKey 123457

a.       FirstName

b.       LastName

c.       EmailAddress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Registrations sent from the Marketing Cloud Mobile Push SDKs are *device* specific and are *not* persisted through a re-installation process.  The `ContactKey` will tie all of a user's devices into 1 Contact Record.  If you are not setting a `ContactKey` for the known user then what you are seeing is correct.

See:

[Setting a Contact Key for iOS](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/sdk-implementation/user-data.html#contact-key)

[Setting a Contact Key for Android](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/sdk-implementation/device-contact-registration.html#contact-key)

Comment: 1. I did the installation IOS device and the following ContactKey is generated:
ac16847d-1472-48b2-9a0e-99b3ea873aec

Now I uninstalled the app.

2. After I uninstalled the app and reinstalled the app on same IOS new contact key is generated:
97b53f64-fb85-4c09-803e-abef315b0282
Once I logged in with the same email address, the above contact key is updated. Ideally I want to merge the two below contact key. Please note that email address and sid in mobile push demographics will always be unique.
a. ac16847d-1472-48b2-9a0e-99b3ea873aec
b. 97b53f64-fb85-4c09-803e-abef315b0282

Comment: We are using below plugin for Mobile Push

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/MC-Cordova-Plugin

Comment: Your follow up comments do not change my answer.  This is working as designed as device IDs do NOT persist an uninstall/re-install.